# Handle JQuery .change() on loop with List of elements in model

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdown

I have a View where I have Dropdown cascade elements
If you select an element on a dropdown, it will get a list and populate another dropdown with the resulting elements. It works if I just have a pair of cascade dropdown, however, if I add multiple cascade dropdown it doesn't work, It just add elements to the first depending dropdown, I know i'ts because it's prohibited to use the same ID, however, I don't know how to make it possible. (To have multiple cascade dropdown)

The Ajax code is the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#CC").change(function () {
            $("#CustomerId").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomersByCC")',

                dataType: 'json',

                data: { id: $("#CC").val() },


                success: function (states) {


                    $.each(states, function (i, CustomerId) {
                        $("#CustomerId").append('<option value="' + CustomerId.Value + '">' +
                            CustomerId.Text + '</option>');

                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Error getting cost centers' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
```

And on the view I have:

```
     @model List<FlexCart.Data.Context.OrderItem>
     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
     {
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].CCId,
     IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CCIds, 
     htmlAttributes: new { id = "CC", @class = "form--control"})

     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[0].CustomerId,
     new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), 
     htmlAttributes: new { id = "CustomerId", @class = "form-control"})
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use relative selectors. jQuery `closest` and `find` method will come handy.

First, wrap each row inside a container div.Also remove the `Id` selector because duplicate `Id`s are invalid. Give a css class for both the dropdowns, which we will use for the relative selectors later.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
   <div class="item-row">

       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].CCId, ViewBag.CCIds as List<SelectListItem>,
                                     new { @class = "ccid form--control" })

       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[0].CustomerId,
                                    new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"),
                                    new { @class = "customer form-control" })

   </div>
}
```

Now, in your change event

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("SELECT.ccid").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var $customer = $(this).closest(".item-row").find("SELECT.customer");

        $customer.empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomersByCC")',
            data: { id: val },
            success: function(states) {
                var options = '';
                $.each(states, function(i,c) {
                    options+= '<option value="' + c.Value + '">' + c.Text + '</option>';
                });
                $customer.append(options);
            },
            error: function(ex) {
                alert('Error getting cost centers' + ex);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

The `$(this).closest(".item-row")` selector gives us the wrapper div and `.find("SELECT.customer")` will give the customer select element inside that container div.